# How to change the type of a number that is written to a csv file?

Tags: python, csv, format

I'm trying to write a float as an integer. However, I get commas when I format the float. What am I doing wrong? An example of this is:

```
cycles = 22.0

with open('test' + '.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(( "%.0f" % cycles ))
```

However, `test.csv` is `2,2`. How, do I get `22`?

Comment: You don't need to convert the value to a string. Just use `writer.writerow((int(cycles),))` (or `writer.writerow([int(cycles)])`). Note the extra comma inserted in the first one, which causes a `tuple` to be created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in

```
writer.writerow(( "%.0f" % cycles ))
```

you're trying to create a `tuple` somehow but you fail: protecting expression with parenthesis doesn't make it a `tuple` (parenthesis is used for both tuples and expression grouping, hence the problem), and bad luck: it (kind of) works: the resulting string is an iterable, so `writerow` writes 1 cell per character exactly like if you had done `writer.writerow("%.0f" % cycles)`

Fixes:

```
writer.writerow(( "%.0f" % cycles, ))
```

or using `list` (no need for comma in that case, I recommend that approach):

```
writer.writerow(["%.0f" % cycles])
```

Note that if you're using `csv` to write only 1 value per row you get more annoyances than benefits (for instance: your code won't work with python 3 because you cannot pass a binary file to `csv.writer`)